# Changes to source code not reflected

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

Sorry if this is a simple question but i am new to programming. I am currently working on a project using Eclipse. When I make changes to the code I usually save the changes then run the ant builder. But, when I run the program the changes are not reflected at all in the running program.

If it helps I had to add the res folder to the classpath before I was able to actually run it before.

Comment: It is very vague; there is not nearly enough detail in this question.

Comment: Ok well some more detail the project uses ant to build. When i builded and ran the project initially i needed to manually add the res folder in the classpath and from then on it worked. whenever I rebuild and run the program it runs the previous version. For example: If the program starts full screen by default and I minimize it before closing, the next time i rebuild and run it opens in the previous minimized state. AKA It keeps the preferences from before. So changes i make to the source code are never reflected in the project even after i rebuild and run.

Comment: Try and "clean" the output directory first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Mad Programmer, You need to do clean build of the project.

You can execute any ant "target" in eclipse. Open then the build.xml, click the "outline" view, and you will see the targets listed in green bubble from. Right-click the one that you would like to run, select "run as", and then "ant build". You should be able to run the target up already.

In addition of the answer, if you are looking for a way to interact with eclipse from ant, this may help you: [Ant tasks provided by the platform.](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ant_eclipse_tasks.htm)

There you can find some task to interact with the platform, like one to cause eclipse to do an incremental build.

Apart from that you might want to look at [this article](http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/using-ant-with-eclipse)

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2nql2/5

Comment: i ran clean, clean build, and just the normal build and the program is still exactly the same. In addition i removed the res folder from the classpath (which was originally needed for it to run) and it still works?

Comment: @LucasNetal What is the content of you ant file.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/d1CYXjXR

Comment: any ideas guys? Im actually really pressed for time right now. I have other partners that are working on the same project code and they arent having my issue

Comment: SOLVED: The program was still running and I had to exit it in the tray

Comment: @LucasNetal Good news. I was still trying to understand your ant file.

Comment: Thanks for the effort anyways Ashish. I knew it would turn out being a very simple solution haha.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your project name in project explorer window has any exclamation symbol. If it so then right click the project and choose build path to add/remove any jar files from the "Add build path" window. Now run your code.. It surely run with your changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient information about the scenario. Still you can just manually go into your workspace directory, find all *.class files, and delete those manually. Rebuild and run.